# Scala types class parameter: binding and subclassing - type mismatch

Tags: scala, class, parameters, subclass, type-mismatch

Noobe question. I have the following base trait (could be an abstract class):

```scala
trait EState[S, A] {
  def retrn(a: A): EState[S, A]
  def runState(s: S): (A, S)
}
```

which I will later extend so:

```scala
case class AState[S, A](val f: S => (A, S)) extends EState[S,A] {
  override def retrn(a: A): AState[S, A] = AState({ s: S => (a, s) })
  override def runState(s: S) = f(s)
}
```

The idea is then to use any instance above like this:

```scala
case class StateMonad3[S, A, M[S,A] <: EState[S, A]](m : M[S,A]) {
  def retrn(a: A): EState[S, A] = m.retrn(a)
  def retrni(a: A): StateMonad3[S, A, M] = StateMonad3(m.retrn(a))
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to gnosis_server/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] gnosis_server/examples/lang/scala/StateMonad.scala:138: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : lang.scala.EState[S,A]
[error]  required: M[S,A]
[error]   def retrni(a: A): StateMonad3[S, A, M] = StateMonad3(m.retrn(a))
                                                                      ^
```

I assumed that the `M[S,A]` would be valid for any subclass `EState[S,A]`. So
the constructor should work. But it seems like `M` and `EState` are different 
here. How should this actually be coded?

Additionally, I suspect that that the `S` and `A` in the `M`and the `EState`
are not the same types. Is this correct or are they bound? If not how
should one set this up?

Note: I have searched in the site and found some references to the use of implicits and their use in conversions but could out figure out how to do this. I would like to avoid using such (at least what seems to me to be such) a verbose/complicated solution.

TIA.

Comment: In `StateMonad3(m.retrn(a))`, `m.retrn( a )` evaluates to an instance of `EState[ S, A ]` . Your `StateMonad3` case class expects an argument of type `M[ S, A ]` ( which is a less generic type as `M[ S, A ] <: EState[ S, A ] ` ), so it won't expects any `EState[ S, A ]` which is super class of `M[ S, A ]` but only `M[ S, A ]` or anytype `SM[ S, A ]` such that `SM[ S, A ] <: M[ S, A ]`.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now. So to solve the problem I need only make the constructor accept `EState[S,A]`.  So I can pass it an `AState[S,A]`. Is their any type-magic I can use to make this work: `def retrn(a: A): M[S,A]  = m.retrn(a)`? Or doesn't this make sense. BTW, can you make the comment an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `StateMonad3(m.retrn(a))` piece, `m.retrn(a)` returns `EState[S, A]` but StateMonad3 apply function needs `M[S, A]` which is `EState[S, A]`subclass. Exactly with the same reasoning you cannot pass `AnyVal` to a function which accepts `Int`.

One more improvement, the `val` keyword you used in definition of `AState` is redundant. case class apply function arguments are `val` by default and the will be defined as case class fields.